# How to Delete Permissions from Linkedin App

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to find the answer of something stupid, but I can't. Does anybody know how to remove the "w_member_social" permission from linkedin App (if there is a way to do something like that)? I need this because the client does not want to see the message "- Post, comment and like posts on your behalf" when authorizing linkedin accounts on our application.

[image: Linkedin App Permissons]

[image: Message I want to remove]

Any other suggestion on how to solve that is welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Quick Fix:

> Search for w_member_social string in your backend code if you find it in the configurations just remove it.

**Explanation**:

You can't remove **w_member_social** permission directly from the LinkedIn app, but it can be modified by making changes in the backend code of your application.
You need to follow certain general steps irrespective of the backend you are using:

1. Find out the library you are using for social authentication/OAuth2 service
2. Check library documentation for **Application scopes W.R.T LinkedIn**
3. go to backend configurations/settings file remove the option **w_member_social** from your configuration.

**My Case:**

My application backend was created using the Django framework and for social authentication, we were using [python-social-auth](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html#register-the-application) library. I just navigated to my setting file and commented out **w_member_social** scope/permission.

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SCOPE = [
"r_basicprofile",
"r_emailaddress",
# "w_member_social",
```

]